# Global directory sidebar for vim

Tags: linux, vim, editor, macvim

How can I have a global sidebar for vim? There is a plugin for MacVim named drawer which:

> It's "global", so it
>   always looks the same even when tabs are in use. It also works
>   correctly in full-screen mode. File system commands like :cd are
>   reflected in the drawer, and switching buffers causes the highlighted
>   file to change.

From this link http://usevim.com/2013/03/06/project-drawer/ you can see what I mean
So, my question is **How can I have such functionality in GVim on Linux?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have exactly the same thing because nobody ever wrote it.

But there's always [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) and [NERDTree-Tabs.](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs)

Comment: An alternative to "the drawer" might be CtlrP or using the built in netrw. Nice post by Drew Neil over at Vimcasts talking about vim and "the drawer": http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/